# Customtkinter canvas with scrollable ctk widgets does not resize when changing ctk.set_widget_scaling

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, customtkinter

I am creating a horizontally scrollable canvas with a scrollbar that controls the x position of a `ctkframe`. In this `ctkframe`, I have packed information blocks for my crossword puzzle browser. When using a `customtkinter` widget scaling of 1.0 the crossword blocks fit perfectly in the canvas, however, when this value is increased, they are cut off and I have not found a way to resize the canvas to adjust for this difference in size without everything breaking.

Here is a code snippet for the horizontal scroll frame object:

```
class HorizontalScrollFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, container, master):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.master = master
        # Make the scrollbar
        h_scrollbar = ctk.CTkScrollbar(self, orientation="horizontal")
        h_scrollbar.pack(fill="x", side="bottom", expand=False)
        
        # make the canvas, link it to `h_scrollbar``
        self.canvas = ctk.CTkCanvas(self, bd=7.5, highlightthickness=1, 
                                    xscrollcommand=h_scrollbar.set, background=canvas_bg_colour)
        self.canvas.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        # whenever the user resizes the window, change the scrollregion of h_scrollbar to the 
        # dimensions of the canvas
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', 
                         lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        h_scrollbar.configure(command=self.canvas.xview)

        # this is the frame that is moved by `h_scrollbar` within `self.canvas`
        self.scrollable_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.canvas, corner_radius=0)
        
        self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="w")
```

Here is another code snippet to show how I put widgets in the scroll frame:

```
# This was normally a class by the way but i removed it so there is less stuff to look at

# This contains the horizontal scroll frame
self.container = ctk.CTkFrame(self)

# Instantiating the scroll frame (dont worry about self.master its for something else)
self.horizontal_scroll_frame = HorizontalScrollFrame(self.container, self.master) 

self.container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
self.horizontal_scroll_frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

def _generate_crossword_blocks(self):
    file_name_example = "capitals"
    # `CrosswordInfoBlock` is just a frame with some widgets placed in it, nothing else
    block = CrosswordInfoBlock(self.horizontal_scroll_frame.scrollable_frame, name=file_name_example)
    
    # packing the block in self.horizontal_scroll_frame.scrollable_frame
    block.pack(side="left", padx=5)
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to make the canvas have enough space to accompany the widgets when they are scaled to a larger size with ctk.set_widget_scaling?

EDIT: The solution for this should also be able to decrease the canvas's size when setting the widget scaling to a value under 1.0.

Comment: If you want to expand the canvas if the internal frame is expanded, then what is the point of having the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @acw1668 no I want to expand it if the widget scaling is increased

Answer (score 0):

After more looking, the answer was actually pretty obvious.

In the `HorizontalScrollFrame` class, which inherits from the container `horizontal_scroll_frame`, I had to set the height of the canvas to the required height of the container:

```
self.canvas = ctk.CTkCanvas(self, bd=7.5, highlightthickness=1, xscrollcommand=h_scrollbar.set, 
                            background=canvas_bg_colour, 
                            height=self.container.winfo_reqheight()) # < here
```